# Multiple lights with button that turns one on at a time

Tags: wiring, light, button, lighting

I am an artist trying to make an installation but I'm not too familiar with electrical work.

I want to have multiple light bulbs wired to one button. Each time the button is pushed one light bulb comes on. There will be probably over fifty of these bulbs.

Could you provide some design hints about how do I accomplish this?

**EDIT:**

I've been told I need to be more specific so I will try with some additional background.

I have a certified electrician who can help me understand language and execution if needed.

I would be using either 40 watt, 60 watt, or 25 watt bulbs. The kind of light bulb simply needs to have that classic look and be relatively cheap, so I'm not concerned about how bright it is. Those are just bulbs within my price range (because I need a lot of them).

The goal is to have a large long arched trellis with light bulbs hanging/on the sides looking similar to string lights. these bulbs would respond to one button and every time the button is pushed a singular light comes on.

Edit** The bulbs would stay on. I'm willing to hear anything anyone has to offer regardless of price, no need

Comment: there are numerous ways of doing it, from using logic gates to using a mcu... without knowing your skills / parts availability, it is hard to be more specific.

Comment: Please be more specific, for guidance on asking questions visit the help center. Questions that are low quality will be closed (they generate multiple bad answers such as the ones listed below)

Comment: He's "an artist" that's "not too familiar with electrical work" and I assume that he has the resourcefulness and finances to buy parts from a shop.  Reading the question is the first step to answering it.

Comment: If this is all you want your thing to do, we need to know what type of bulbs you want.  Is it a little LED like the standby one on your telly, or like the 60W one on your ceiling or something else like a garden security /flood light?  Or something even elser?  And is it indoors or outdoors?  You have to bear with the comments here, engineers typically have issues of English comprehension.  Please edit the question and we'll go from there...

Comment: Light bulbs can be connected to any lightning socket in a house. Those are rated 110VAC (220V depending on your country) and some watts (60W lets say).

Imagine you have the 110V power source connected to a 15A, wired with 14AWG cable 24 light bulbs in parallel.

If you use the newest LED light bulbs, they consume about 20W, you will be able to connect 75 LED light bulbs.

Now, there are small light bulbs rated 12VAC, and diodes rated for 3VDC. In that case you will need a transformer or adapter to reduce the power coming out from your electrical outlet in your house to your project.

Comment: @PaulUszak this forum is moderated, there are questions that are off topic. We don't do other people's shopping for them here, those types of questions run counter to SE's mission https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad

Comment: @laptop2d I think that we're back to the stuff I said about reading the question and comprehension aren't we?

Comment: Sorry, but I think that we need another edit.  When you say one bulb comes on at a time, do the others stay on or go off? All bulbs on will be circa 3000 watts which is easily dealt with but needs to be known from the start.  Do you realise that each bulb will require it's own power cable running all the way back to a custom control box stuffed with electronics and perhaps a mini computer that you'll have to build?  Do you have the resources to proceed if we help?

Comment: @PaulUszak We'll let the moderators decide, it would be great if you could spends some time in the help center looking at guidelines and some time in the meta.EE.SE to understand how EE.SE works. Thanks

Comment: @laptop2d it be great if you stop acting like judge and jury in these things as well...

Comment: @Passerby Keep up the good work

Comment: @flannelsupreme For a forum where you WILL get a good answer. (1) Read [**this page**](http://www.piclist.com/techref/piclist/index.htm?url=www.) - Ignore the links except the following one. [2] Go to [**this page](http://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/piclist) read it (overlap with above) and then join the list by filling in the boxes at the bottom. Hopefully you'll get a "welcome" email. Send questions to piclist@mit.edu  . Put [EE] in the start of your subject line and a subject line (this one is fine) and ask away. Helpful people will guide you to an answer :-) | No spam. Leave anytime.

Comment: If you have a certified electrician helping you, why don't you ask him to just build this for you?

Comment: With the additional information, I would put forth a MCU plus shift register solution. Something like a pic12f675 Pluss a few 74hc164 or hc595 would work. The bulbs can be switched via relays. The whole thing would cost this side of 5usd before factoring the relays.

Comment: Another approach is to use PLC. Finding one with 50 contacts can be tough however. But your electrician friend may be more familiar with it.

Comment: Sorry I tried, but you've been deemed as unwanted by our little merry band.  Good luck.

Comment: Sorry if my question was inappropriate for this site to all that were disgruntled! Just trying to get some insight. Also thank you to all those who provided advice and information that I would not otherwise have :)

Comment: I think it is a shame that your question was deemed inappropriate. the community could have really helped you get where you want to be, while making it a learning experience for you. too bad that that wasn't happening here. I feel bad for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of microcontroller-based solution, plus some relays and a power supply.

Given your background and project needs (50 bulbs), I'd recommend you to use an **Arduino Mega 2560**, plus several boards of 10+ relays (or, even better, SSRs), and an AC/DC power supply with a high current rating for all the current that the relays will draw.

Also, you'll be better off posting this question to the Arduino site in stack exchange.

Comment: thank you for your advice! I'm looking into those supplies now.

Answer (score 1):

After your clarification, what I've said below may not directly work, but you can still do something similar to control them (send a single 1 instead of series). However, switching higher-current bulbs will definitely need some type of driver. Or you can go with old-school relay logic. :) But, if you don't want to design something from scratch, consider something like the Insteon or X10 home automation modules. You could then program a scene that switches to a different bulb.

--

It depends on how you want the lights to come on. If it's going to be like a bar graph I'd use seven simple 8-bit shift registers, like a 74LS594, plus a debounce RC circuit. Depending on how much current you're sinking or sourcing, you may also need some drive transistors or relays.

Your button would be connected to the clock line of the registers and you'd have a second button for clearing them. You'd wire the input of the first register to Vcc to produce 1s. As the 1s get shifted through the registers each subsequent output goes from 0 to 1, which would be used to turn on your bulb.

To explain further how this works, it uses a series of shift registers. The register I recommended has a serial input, and serial output, and a parallel output. Every time it receives a clock signal, all of the bits are shifted one position. After the reset button is pushed, all of the bits are set to zero, so all of the lights would be off. Here's what the initial state looks like:

1-in-->[0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0]--out----in-->[0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0]--out...

The first "in" pin is wired to Vcc (power) to produce a 1. When the clock button is pushed, all of the bits shift over one:

1-in-->[1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0]--out----in-->[0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0]--out...

So the first light is lit. Continuing to push the button continues to shift the bits, turning on more lights:

1-in-->[1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0]--out----in-->[0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0]--out...

1-in-->[1|1|1|0|0|0|0|0]--out----in-->[0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0]--out...

1-in-->[1|1|1|1|0|0|0|0]--out----in-->[0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0]--out...

Pushing reset would set everything back to 0, turning all of the lights off.

The parallel outputs would be used to turn on a light.

If you wanted a single light turned on, you'd need a method to send a single 1 into the input and follow it with zeros. You could do that with adding a flip-flop, a switch, or NOR gate in front to change the bit stream. It would be similar as before:

1-in-->[0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0]--out----in-->[0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0]--out...

0-in-->[0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0]--out----in-->[0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0]--out...

0-in-->[0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0]--out----in-->[0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0]--out...

0-in-->[0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0]--out----in-->[0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0]--out...

Comment: I strongly suggest you try the site I mentioned. | Your 'how it works' description is still unclear. You need to spell it out. Are there eg 50 bulbs and pressing one button or several buttons advannces 1 light per time 1 2 3 4 ... 50, or goups of lights that do this, or ???

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I only saw a mention to the OP to go to the PIC listserv; which site are you suggesting? | The original post was unclear what was needed, so I provided general guidance on how to start to design a controller. But I'll be happy to expand on what the idea is.

Comment: The [PICList](http://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/piclist) is what I waqs suggesting. Despite the name it is far from being solely list oriented. It has people with an extremely wide cross-section of experience and an atmosphere conducive to casual Q&A if required. I'd see it as complementary to SE. Traffic level is far lower with large bursts when a suitably 'intense' topic arises.